# How do I solve an untracked content when git adding content?

Tags: github, server

I have a React/Node project and I want to push it to github, but when I git add ., the client side is added, but server side not. When typing git status, I get the error below:

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
modified:   server (untracked content)

I have also tried git add -A and didn't work